# Monotouch: Play movie without interrupting audio of other apps e.g. iPod

Tags: xamarin.ios, mpmovieplayer, avaudiosession

I have a silent movie (No sound at all in that clip) which acts as a background movie for my view.

When I play music with iPod and then open my app the iPod music stops.

I don´t want my movie to interrupt the iPod Audio. I´ve read that UseApplicationAudioSession is deprecated but how do I realize this now?

Thank you for your help!

**EDIT:** And because I add an image onto the MovieplayerViewController I can not use AVPlayer.

PS: Other threads I´ve found here do mention the deprecated UseApplicationAudioSession solution thats why I opened a new question.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
AVAudioSession audioSession = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance();

                    NSError audioSessionError = new NSError();

                    audioSession.SetCategory(new NSString("AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient"), out audioSessionError);
```